# Data packet reception via bluetooth at android GUI

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am pretty new to both arduino as well as the android domains. I am using arduino to send data to android using bluetooth module(linvor JY-MCU v.1.05). It is communicating with my app perfectly but i am not able to receive any data for this particular app. I am transferring a packet from arduino => ( $ 43 56 ! ) I want to extract it and display numbers alone on the android app.
Here `$-header, 43-hr value, 56-temp value, !-footer`

**My arduino code is as follows:**

```
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>


  SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
  String command = "";             // Stores response of bluetooth device
                           // which simply allows \n between each
                           // response.


  void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600); // initialization

  delay(25);
  }

  void loop() 

  {
  mySerial.println("$-43:56^!");  // print   message


  delay(5000);
  }
```

The string is like a packet. I want 43 to be displayed in an editbox and 56 to be displayed in a text box.

My android code is a vast one that checks bluetooth connectivity too. So i am limiting it to just a section. Could someone please help me out with the coding part of it to just display the two sets of numbers in two txtView1 and txtView2 respectively....

```
    package com.example.projtrial;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import com.example.projtrial.R;


    import android.R.string;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String TAG = "projtrial";

  public EditView editView1;
  public TextView textView1;
  Handler h;

final int RECEIVE_MESSAGE = 1;       //Handler status
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

//SPP UUID service
  private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-    00805F9B34FB");       
// MAC-address of Bluetooth module 
  private static String address = "20:13:05:13:01:98";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);       
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

h = new Handler() {
    private String strIncom;
private String header;
    private String hr;
    private String tempr;
    private String footer;


public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

switch (msg.what) {
        case RECEIVE_MESSAGE:   // If one receives a message                                

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String header = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

            String[] separated = message.split("\\:");
            editText1.setText("hr: " + separated[0]);  //works
            textView1.setText("temp:" + separated[1]); //doesnt work
               }
            break;    
    }

};

};


btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
checkBTState();

}
private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws        IOException {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
        try {
            final Method  m =   device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        }
    }
    return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

  // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
  BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

  // Two things are needed to make a connection:
  //   A MAC address, which we got above.
  //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
  //     UUID for SPP.

try {
    btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
} catch (IOException e) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
}

  /*try {
    btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
  }*/

  // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
  // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
  btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

  // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
  Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
  try {
    btSocket.connect();
    Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    try {
      btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
      errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
  }

  // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
  Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

  mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
  mConnectedThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();

  Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

  try     {
    btSocket.close();
  } catch (IOException e2) {
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
  }
}

private void checkBTState() {
  // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
  // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
  if(btAdapter==null) { 
    errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
  } else {
    if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
      Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
    } else {
      //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
      Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
      startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
    }
  }
}

private void errorExit(String title, String message){
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  finish();
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


  public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
              h.obtainMessage(RECEIVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();       // Send to message queue Handler
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
/*
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
  */
            }
      }
        }
   }
```

Someone please help me out soon. I have been stuck up with dis for over a week. Thanking you in advance.
                   Sanj

"Case receive" and "Run" are the loops where the change has to be made. 
Finding the index of a character "indexOf()" provides an error(string index out of bound). 
I have tried switching off the bluetooth after entering the case receive block too but in vain. 
Hoping to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

what does Message contains? with

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
String header = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
```

all the consecutive

```
 byte[] readBuf2 = (byte[]) msg.obj; 
 String hr = new String(readBuf2, 0, msg.arg1);
```

you are extrancing always the same data.
given the fact that in obj there are the chars between `$` and `!` included, then you can read all message

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
String message = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
```

and then extract all the line

```
String[] cell = message.split("\n");
txtView1.setText("HR:" +cell[1]);
[...]
```

if in obj instead there are some byte[], then you have to add them to a buffer, then you remove all byte until `$`, add byte[] until you find a `!`, extract and remove from the buffer the data between the two delimeter, inclusive, and do what i said before. (well, this is just one solution)

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried what you suggested but I don't seem to split it well. I can display only the 1st half say cell[0] in a text box, txtView1. But when I try displaying cell[1], the application crashes. I get the error, "array index out of bounds". The other problem I face is that I am not able to split up data and display in both the text views at the same time. I have edited only the case receive part of it, the rest of the code is the same. I have added it in the edit part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Now right off the bat I haven't used bluetooth before but I'd say that the problem could be at these lines:

```
mySerial.println("$");  // print   message

mySerial.println(23);

mySerial.println(546);

mySerial.println("!");
```

Because you are using println(); you send the message at each line as a separate packet hence the receiving end can't split it up and use the information.

I had a similar problem and fixed it by simply putting all the data needed in one string and the sending the whole string once.

The arduino coding language also for some reason cant join an integer and a string to another string just like that, It took me a while to figure it out but you simply have to use lines similar to this:

```
String output = "$";
output += 23; //or "23", not sure if it matters which one you use.
output += 546;
output += "!";
mySerial.println(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it still doesn't seem to help me.